# How to find out if first simbol is "_" and if true remove it and make first letter capital?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, unity-game-engine

We have a string (`0 .. N` simbols long). How to find out if its first simbol is `"_"` and if true remove it and make first letter capital (fro example `"_distance"` `=>` `"Distance"`)?

I wondered in general - so stupid I am, while I was investigating creation of Unity3d `CustomEditor` Components visiable to `Inspector`. So idea was - if class feild starts with `_` do parsing etc.

But it appeares that in Unity3d for private class fields which are usually written like `_name` when you flag it with something like `[SerializeField]` inspector **will** do such thing automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very trivial, actually:

```
if (s.StartsWith("_")) {
  s = s.Substring(1, 1).ToUpper() + s.Substring(2);
}
```

Reads almost the same as your description, actually. And it will fail if *N* is less than 2. But you can check for that separately, e.g.:

```
if (s.Length >= 2 && s.StartsWith("_"))
```

Comment: I would use `s.StartsWith("_")` as test, so that you don't have to check for empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if (s != null && s.Length >= 2 && s[0] == '_') {
    s = Char.ToUpper(s[1]) + s.Substring(2);
}
```

If you know that `s` cannot be `null`, drop the first test.

```
if (s.Length >= 2 && s[0] == '_') {
    s = Char.ToUpper(s[1]) + s.Substring(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Messy one-liner:

```
String name = "_distance";
name = (name.StartsWith("_") ? (name.Length > 1 ? name.Substring(1, 1).ToUpper() + (name.Length > 2 ? name.Substring(2) : "") : "") : name);
```

Clearer version of the one-liner:

```
String name = "_distance";
if (name.StartsWith("_"))
{
    if (name.Length > 1)
    {
        name = name.Substring(1, 1).ToUpper() + (name.Length > 2 ? name.Substring(2) : "");
    }
    else
    {
        name = "";
    }
}
```

Extention version:

```
public static String ParseCapitalize(this String str)
{
    if (str == null)
        return "";
    if (str.StartsWith("_"))
    {
        if (str.Length > 1)
        {
            return str.Substring(1, 1).ToUpper() + (str.Length > 2 ? str.Substring(2) : "");
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
    return str;
}

//Usage:
String s = "_this is a string";
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    s = s.ParseCapitalize();
```

These snippets will handle:

"" => ""

"_" => ""

"_a" => "A"

"_asd" => "Asd"

"asd" => "asd"

(For the extention only) null => ""

Comment: @Pluc You should check for null in your extension method to avoid potential NRE.

Comment: @Pluc Nope, you must check for NRE. Extension methods are just syntactic sugar for some static methods that take a normal parameter as input. Just test your code with a `string z = null; z.ParseCapitalize();`, a NRE is thrown in your extension method, not in its calling code. EDIT: you fixed the code in the meantime :)

Comment: Heh, I tested it after posting the comment ^^ Thanks for the info!